# How to install magento extension on 2.1.5 version?

Tags: magento, magento2

I'd like to use magento cli to install magento2 extensions like this;

exto-analytics-1.0.7
emagicone-module-bridgeconnector-1.0.3
livechat-module-magento-livechat-2.0.0

My hosting server name is *magemojo.com*.
I am a magento begineer, So need to help anything now.
I am trying to use cli likes as ves_setup or php f magento...
What can I do for it?
Please tell me any ideas, Thanks ~

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?

Answer (score 0):

You can install magento via FTP put folder content in root directory of magento 2 installation.

Run `magento setup:upgrade`

Thanks